# Euler 4, Modulo issue

Tags: python-3.x

Newbie programmer fresh off of code academy. I wanted to keep going so I started the Euler examples. I've got to no.4, https://projecteuler.net/problem=4:

My program is getting to the number 980089 happily enough but decides that this number is divisible by 994. But the other value is actually 986.0050302. That isn't the answer that I'm looking for. So modulo isn't doing its job because there is a remainder of 0.0050302. Why is this happening?

Full code:

```
x = 999998
g = 2
while g < 99:
    e = str(x)
    if e[::-1] == str(x):
        print(e)
        for f in reversed(range(100, 1000)):
            f = float(f)
            h = x/f
            if int(x) % f == 0.000000 and h < 1000:
                print("%s and %s" % (f, h))
                break
            else:
                x = x - 1
    else:
        x = x - 1
```

Tips on how I could improve my code would be great too, I don't think my **while** command was used how I originally imagined.

Comment: There is much wrong with your code, but the very first thing is: don't use floats for integer math.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't do it.

Comment: of course that didn't do it. your code is very broken. but at least it should now be clear that 994 does not divide 980089.

Comment: Thanks but no, it didn't correct it. It still says 994.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the general idea of what you're trying to do is to start at a number larger than anything two 3-digit numbers could multiply to, and then just start going down by one seeing if there are any possible 3-digit numbers that will multiply to your current number.

First thing I notice is that your while loop uses `g`, but you never modify it inside your loop, so it's rather useless. I also notice you're casting `x` to an int using `int(x)` at one point, which is not needed because `x` will always already be an int.

I'm going to try and rewrite your code to do the right thing - let me know if you have any questions about it!

```
x = 999998
found_an_answer = False    

# We'll certainly find an answer before we get here
while x > 10000:

    # get the string version of the number
    x_string = str(x)

    # See if its the same as its reverse
    if x_string == x_string[::-1]:

        # Print out the palindrome we're currently looking at
        print ("Looking for 3-digit factors of " + x_string)

        # Let's try all the factors from 999 to 100
        for f in reversed(range(100, 1000)):

            # First, check if f is a factor of x by checking if the
            #  remainder is 0 when we divide x by f.
            # Then, check if the other factor, x/f, is less than 1000
            #  to make sure it is three digits
            if x%f == 0 and x/f < 1000:

                # If we made it here, we found the number!!
                print("Found the number!")
                print("Number: {}".format(x))
                print("Factors: {}, {}".format(f, x/f))

                # We set this to be true because using a "break"
                # statement will only break out of the inner most
                # loop (the one where we're modifying f
                found_an_answer = True
                break

        # Now that we left the inner loop, we can check the
        #  found_an_answer variable to see if we should
        #  break out of the outer loop to.
        if found_an_answer:
            break

    # Guess we didn't find an answer yet.  LEt's look at the next
    #  smallest number.
    x = x-1
```

One more little thing - instead of having using a while loop and manually decreasing x inside it, you could just do a for loop counting down, by changing the loop to be

```
for x in range(999998, 10000, -1):
```

Then you don't need the `x=999998` line or the `x = x-1` line.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on this. For g, I had a plan for it but I started getting the results I wanted without correcting it so I carried on. Also attempts with int and float were me trying to get it working properly.

Comment: Other then being ugly and poorly laid out. The mathematical functions are largely the same. Can you detect why I don't get the same values as you?

Comment: Hey @AlecDavies it looks like your problem is that you are decreasing x by 1 inside of your for loop which modifies f.  So you're iterating over all possible values of f to see if one of them is a factor of x, but if you're going to do that, you need to have the same x as you go through all of the values of f.

Comment: For example, the first palindromic value for x is 998899.  So when you get into that inner for loop, you start with f=999, right? You then check if 999 is a factor of 998899, and it's not, so your program runs the "else" block, which decrements x, giving you x=998898. And now the for loop goes into its next iteration, with f=998, so now we're checking if 998 is a factor of 998898 instead of 998899.  But what we *should* be doing is checking all values for f for EACH value of x.  I hope that makes sense! Also if an answer here solves your problem, please mark it as accepted if you don't mind :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I put that in as a solution to stop it getting stuck on a palindrome. Now I've removed the it and the outer else statement and it works. Much appreciated, thank you.